# How to determine what bin a float should be in? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, conditional-statements

I have an array of floats `Float_t xbins[41]` that defines 40 bins i.e. ranges of floats.
E.g. `y` is in bin 7 if `y > xbins[7] && !(y > xbins[8])`.

How do I determine what bin a given float should belong to without having 40 if statements?

Please answer in C++ as I don't speak other languages.

Comment: I have no clue what you want.

Comment: You did not tell me the criteria by which a "bin" should be chosen, how can we tell you a better way to  implement those criteria then?

Comment: What are the ranges of float for each bin? Are they entirely arbitrary, or can the bin number simply be calculated?

Comment: @JackAidley: 42 bins if you count the values below the first and above the last boundary. 40 if you don't.

Comment: So binx[] contains an array of start/end points for binning? So for any `x` you want to find a position such that `xbins[n] <= x && xbins[n+1] > x`? Correct?

Comment: @JackAidley, yes correct. The bins are not uniform i.e. they start in steps of 1, but finish in steps of 5.

Comment: Hmm...  the Question actually seems quite clear. It's troubling that some readers would close it simply for not understanding it.

Answer (score 4):

If the array is sorted, then do a binary search to locate the correct bin. You'll need a combination of `std::sort` (if not sorted), then something like `std::lower_bound`, to locate. You'll need to ensure that `operator<` is implemented correctly for `Float_t`.

Comment: thanks, std::lower_bound seems to be what I need.

Comment: The only way those 41 floats can define 40 bins is that the array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out that the bins are not uniformly spaced but have integer bounds, the probably fastest method is to have a (inverse) look up table that apparently has about 100 entries. One needs to make basically two comparisons for the lower & higher bounds.

If the array bounds are derived with a formula, it could be possible to write an inverse formula that outperforms the LUT method.

For a generic case binary search is the way -- and even that can be improved a bit by doing linear interpolation instead of exactly subdividing the range to half. The speed (if the data is not pathological) would be O(loglogn) compared to O(logn) for binary search.